# can not get headers from response in Ext.Ajax.request success callback

Tags: extjs, header, response

I am using Ext.Ajax.request(in sencha toucn 2.3) to post data to my backend server.
And i want to read some custom headers from the "response" parameter of the "success" callback like this:

`response.getResponseHeader('x-user-session');`

i am quite sure the backend server send back many headers and the 'x-user-session' header also present, but what strange is: when using the "response" object, i can get only one header : "content-type".

this question has already been asked here: [ExtJS 4.2.1: Cannot retrieve HTTP Response headers upon Ext.ajax.request callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066550/extjs-4-2-1-cannot-retrieve-http-response-headers-upon-ext-ajax-request-callbac) , but there is no answer yet.

I have already tried debug into the "Ext.data.Connection" class, and found the headers of "response" object in "Ext.data.Connection" also contains only "content-type" header.

could anybody tell me why this happened? is there something wrong in my backend program? or just a bug of Ext.Ajax? how can i get the value of my custom header 'x-user-session'?

thanks ~~

==================ANSWER=====================

i finally got the answer from sencha forum: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?289879-the-response-for-Ext.Ajax.request-doesn-t-include-all-response-headers

here is the part about the headers:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers (optional) - 
The XMLHttpRequest 2 object has a getResponseHeader() method that returns the value of
 a particular response header. During a CORS request, the getResponseHeader() method 
can only access simple response headers. 
Simple response headers are defined as follows:

Cache-Control
Content-Language
Content-Type
Expires
Last-Modified
Pragma

If you want clients to be able to access other headers, you have to use the 
Access-Control-Expose-Headers header. The value of this header is a comma-delimited 
list of response headers you want to expose to the client.
```

i haven't verify it yet, but it seems on the right track :)

enclosed the screen captures:

[image: the headers returned from backend server]
[image: response.getAllResponseHeaders() only return "content-type"]

Comment: This is very interesting and seems like it'd work, but unfortunately, it did not solve the problem in my app.  Nice post though, exactly what I was looking for.