# Getting response headers from Ajax POST in ExtJS

Tags: ajax, extjs, http-headers

Given this `Ext.Ajax` call:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    jsonData: dataToPost,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response.getAllResponseHeaders());
        console.log(response.getResponseHeader('Location'));
        console.log(response.getResponseHeader('location'));
    });
}
```

I expected to see the Location: header in the log.  Instead I get this (I added the lower-case location just in case, seeing content-type is lower-case):

[image]

The same request seen in Fiddler shows more headers than Content-type:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of ExtJS are you using? Have tested width 6.2.1 as it shows me all the response headers. Here is the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1nps)

Comment: Version is 6.2.0 GPL

Comment: From the top right corner of sencha fiddle you can select which ExtJS version you want to use. With ExtJS 6.2.0 it also works as expected for me. Are you able to reproduce your problem in the fiddle?

Comment: your are life saver @scebotari66  please post has answer.

Comment: Probably because you are using cors on your server https://stackoverflow.com/a/25227348/11078199